# Set alt attribute when using imagephp()

Tags: php

Is it possible to output an image with a predetermined alt attribute?

```
$im = @imagecreatefrompng($file)
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Outputs the image. I want to set the alt attribute before output - can I do so?

Comment: That is just plain text and gets output with your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your code outputs the **raw image**. *Not* any HTML tags. Your alt tag needs to be included in the HTML where the img tag is.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.

All element attributes are in your HTML.  When you're outputting an image resource, it's just an image.  It's a completely separate resource.

Comment: Thought as much, unfortunately.

Comment: Why is this unfortunate? Certainly you are in control of the code generating the img tag as well, no?